# How can I compile a python 3.3 program (which uses pygame) into a Windows executable?

Tags: python, pygame, exe

I have made a hangman-style game with python 3.3 using pygame and I would like to compile it somehow, so that it can be run on another computer, which doesn't have python or pygame installed (if that is possible). I've done some research on this, and I found that you can use py2exe, but I found that this isn't for python 3.3 yet (correct me if I'm wrong), so is there another way of doing this? I have also seen something about cx_Freeze, but I just can't understand how to use it.

Here is a download link for a .zip with all the files in it (images, sounds, etc.):
https://www.dropbox.com/s/4187t1mv9iszwjh/Hangman%20Game.zip

How can I make that program into a windows executable? Also, if it is possible, how can I make it so that everything I need is in one .exe file and there aren't any .dll or external files of that sort?

Just letting you know, I'm a programming noob, so I cannot guarantee I'll understand answers that are not noobified. Also, I am new to this site, so if I do something wrong or unconventional, please let me know. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes use something like [Python 3 to 2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/3to2) i think thats the only one thing to change 3 to 2 
and there are a few that will compile it but i recommend using [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) the thing is it will make and  .exe file but there might be dependencies that have to be with the file but there are ways to get rid of those and put it all in one program

py2exe can be confusing so heres a [Tutorial](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial)

also i recommend organizing your game images into differnt folders it makes it easier

Comment: Here's a demo file using py2exe /w pygame http://www.pygame.org/wiki/Pygame2exe?parent=CookBook

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html that should explain you basically download it then run it with youre selected program from the command line kinda like this `2to3 example.py`

Answer (score 0):

I found this, it might not work:
[3to2 1.0](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/3to2)

 Then you can use [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) on the code.