# How do I convert a python 3 file with pygame to an exe

Tags: python, pygame

I've already tried cx_FREEZE, but it crashes on install. I don't remember what else I tried but it obviously also didn't work. The FILE is python 3. It uses PYGAME. I need to convert it to an EXE. I tried the "Solution" here: [How can I compile a python 3.3 program (which uses pygame) into a Windows executable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17002293/how-can-i-compile-a-python-3-3-program-which-uses-pygame-into-a-windows-execut) , however I cannot find any documentation on how to use the program.

Comment: AFAIK py2exe doesn't support python 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's some sort of bug when you try to use cx_freeze with Python 3.x and Pygame.

You need to include these lines of code in your main program:

```
import re
includes = ["re"]
import pygame._view
```

This solved the problem for me.

And this is what my **setup.py** script looks like:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
exe = Executable(
script="game.py",
)

setup(
    executables = [exe]
    )

# go to C:\Python32 in CMD prompt and type 'c:\python32\python.exe setup.py build'
```